# Combining slicing and advanced indexing in python Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, slice

I'm trying, unsuccessfully, to combine numpy array slicing and advanced indexing. For example I have a numpy array filled with 1/0's

```
r = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

I find the indexes of non zero elements :

```
(nz,) = np.nonzero(r)
```

I would then like to use the array of non zero indexes to operate on my array r. For each index in r I would like to colour a range (in the below 5) of values forward in r. Something like -

```
r[nz,:nz:nz+5] = 255
```

which gives result :

array([  0,   0, 255, 255,   0, 255,   0,   0, 255,   0, 255,   0,   0,
         0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0])

I would however have expected the following :

array([  0,   0, 255, 255,   255 , 255,   255,   255 , 255,   255 , 255,   255,   255,
         255,   255,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0])

given my indexing [nz,:nz:nz+5] = 255. Which I believe to mean from current index nz to nz+5 set value to 255.

My objective is to avoid having to for-loop iterate over the array for efficiency reasons. I'm relatively new to python and numpy so all suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Can you please edit your question with a sample input and expected output?

Comment: This is an index error, just was a bug in some older numpy versions that it is allowed at all. You have two indices for one dimension.

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a matrix of the slices:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> r = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
>>> nz = np.nonzero(r)
>>> slices = np.vstack(np.arange(x, x + 5) for x in nz[0])
>>> slices
array([[ 2,  3,  4,  5,  6],
       [ 3,  4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11, 12],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]], dtype=int64)
>>> r[slices]
array([[1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
>>> r[slices] = 255
>>> r
array([  0,   0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
       255, 255,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0])
```

Note that this code assumes that you have enough "padding" at the end. It will fail with an `IndexError` if it tries to index items outside `r`.

Answer (score 0):

Problem description resembles a typical signal convolution step.  There are two modules in scipy that implement signal processing, `scipy.signal` and `scipy.ndimage`, which you may find interesting if you plan doing more of that.  In this particular case, you can use generic `np.convolve` (notice that I added trailing 1 for illustrative purpose):

```
In [45]: r = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1])

In [46]: r[np.convolve(r, np.ones(5, dtype=r.dtype))[:-4] > 0] = 255; r
Out[46]: 
array([  0,   0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
       255, 255,   0,   0,   0,   0, 255])
```

Here's the result of convolution operation:

```
In [48]: np.convolve(r, np.ones(5, dtype=r.dtype))
Out[48]: 
array([0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

As you can see, the last `1` has produced a full sequence of `1`s at the end, they should be stripped.  After that, non-zero elements in convolved array will give you the required boolean mask:

```
In [49]: np.convolve(r, np.ones(5, dtype=r.dtype))[:-4] > 0
Out[49]: 
array([False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False,
       False,  True], dtype=bool)
```